# Adding new symbols in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible in `gdb` to define variables without those variables being loaded in a file? For example:

```
>>> set var i=4 # how to do int i=4; ?
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

Basically, I'd like to use `gdb` as a way to learn a bit more about the language and define variables within the prompt (like a python prompt) without having to have those variables pre-loaded in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the purpose of gdb is inspecting programs, the usual assumption within expressions is that an identifier names some variable belonging to the current program. But gdb does also have "debugger convenience variables". A name starting with a `$` symbol is either a register (one of several defined by the executable's target CPU architecture) or a debugger convenience variable.

So:

```
(gdb) set $i = 4
```

However, I definitely don't recommend using these "as a way to learn a bit more about the language". gdb will support most of C's syntax for expressions that include them, but it's only faking it, and they're really not at all the same type of thing as a C variable. For just one example, a convenience variable never has an address. So any experimenting you would do with those variables would just reveal the behavior of gdb's prompt language and that sort of variable, which won't always be the same as the C language and its variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [convenience variables](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).

```
set $myvar = 15
```

Then you can print their value as any other variable

```
p $myvar
```

Note that convenience variables exist entirely inside gdb and do not affect the program being debugged at all.